# storing and comparing cookies problem in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using PHP and having a problem in storng and comparing cookies values. I want to store two variables in the cookie (name and id). A name can select multiple id's. How can I store name and multiple id's in the cookie?

For example:

```
$name = alex
$id = 1

$name=alex
$id=3
```

Once I have saved these sets in the cookies, I have two new variables:

```
$newname = alex
$newid = 1
```

I want to check if any cookie exists where *$name = $newname* and *$id=$nameid*. 
I hope someone can help me with it. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize an array as a url-encoded string, and store that as a cookie.

Getting the values out you'd have to url-decode the value.